# ReportDir of a mochawesome reporter option in cypress.json to point to folder created at run time named after timestamp

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

I am currently passing `reportDir` under `reporterOptions` inside `cypress.json` file as `testResults/`. I would like to create a new folder at run time named after the timestamp under `testResults` folder and save the generated mochawesome report inside it for each run, Ex: Report location: `testResults/TIMESTAMP/mochawesome-report`.

Also I need to keep track of the new folder name `TIMESTAMP` as I would be saving other files inside this folder at the end of execution. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Note: Using `timestamp` key in `cypress.json` file, I am able to create the `mochawesome-report` file named after timestamp. However, I am looking for the `reportDir` folder named after timestamp.